# Swiperefreshlayout overrides scroll in ScrollView

Tags: java, android

So for some reason my scroll functionallity doesn't work after I implementet a `SwipeRefreshLayout` to my .xml

Why is that?

**XML**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/PTRefresh"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPullToRefresh"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PullToRefresh"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/write"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PullToRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:text="@string/PTRefresh"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPullToRefresh"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/swipe_container" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because Android can't really tell the difference between a swipe to refresh and a swipe to scroll your ScrollView unless you use a NestedScrollView instead.

NestedScrollView was designed to handle exactly that type of scenario. It also works when you have a ScrollView inside another or a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView, and so on.

Comment: but when i change `ScrollView` to `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` it's the same result. And is it possible to only enable the swipetorefresh on the top of the scrollview and not the whole scrollview? because when i want to scroll it wants to refresh

Comment: Try wrapping your TextView with the SwipeToRefreshLayout instead of the ScrollView, that way you'll be able to maintain your ScrollView's normal behaviour and at the same time have your refresh animation when you perform your swipe action on the TextView. Make sure the TextView will give the user enough room to swipe there